# Cannot display image in ImageView after reading from database in Android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, imageview

I was trying to save an image after reading from gallery into database and display it in an ImageView. When I ran my code there is no error, but I can't see my image in ImageView. I will post the relevant codes.

I planned to open gallery when clicked on an ImageView-

```
imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  // imgProfile is object of Imageview
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);       // selectedImagePath is String
            BitmapFactory.Options bOp = new BitmapFactory.Options();  // bmap is Bitmap
            bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, bOp);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bOut);
            img = bOut.toByteArray();                                 // img is byte[]
            db.storeProfilePic(num, img);                    // db is object of database class

            cur = db.readPic(num);  // cur is Cursor. num is used as primary key in the table
            if (cur != null)
            {
                cur.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    img = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("image"));    // img is byte[]
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }

            Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img,0, img.length);
            imgProfile.setImageBitmap(b1);                           // imgProfile is ImageView
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

Function to save image to database-

```
public void storeProfilePic(String user, byte[] img)
{
    String query = "insert into profilePicture(userID, image) values('" + user
            + "', '" + img + "')";
    db1.execSQL(query);                        // db1 is SQLiteDatabase
}
```

Function to read image from database-

```
public Cursor readPic(String ID)
{
    String query = "select image from profilePicture where userID = '" + ID + "'";
    cur = db1.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cur;
}
```

What is the problem in my code ? How should I edit it to make the image displayed in the ImageView ?

Comment: where are you displaying the image? all we can see is you are selecting a cursor. As an aside, storing images in a database isn't a good idea, it would be better to store them as files on the filesystem

Comment: Are you saving Image URLs in Database and if yes then are you getting these urls from database using select Methos ??

Comment: @BalvinderSingh If that is the problem how should I edit my code ?

Comment: @panini Look the if condition after this - cur = db.readPic(num);  Am displaying my image to an ImageView

Comment: @panini Why is saving images to database not a good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

At last when no one else was there to help, I found a solution. I just made some editings and things are working fine now.

```
txtCP.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  // I changed the Imageview from here and put a TextView
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}
```

I only want to save the image to database when ever I click on the TextView object txtCP, but to display it as many times as I come to this activity. So I used SharedPreferences to do that.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true))  // prefs is object of SharedPreferences
    {
        loadProfilePic();
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
    }
}

private void loadProfilePic()
{
    cur = db.readPic(num);
    if (cur != null)
    {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            img = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("image"));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }

    Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
    imgProfile.setImageBitmap(b1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            BitmapFactory.Options bOp = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, bOp);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bOut);
            img = bOut.toByteArray();
            db.storeProfilePic(num, img);

            loadProfilePic();
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

Function to save image to database -

```
public void storeProfilePic(String user, byte[] img)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("userID", user);
    cv.put("image", img);
    db1.insert("profilePicture", null, cv);
}
```

Function to read image from database is same as that in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use this cose:

```
      image.setImageBtmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(url, 200,
        200));

     public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(

BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: where you are getting url from Database put that url in  image.setImageBtmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(url, 200,
        200));

Comment: you can use it in loop if there are multiple urls

Comment: its not a URL in the database, its a blob of data.

Comment: I think you have to save url of Images in database this will make you easy to deal with images else you will get OutofMemory exception later on.

Comment: I need to have these images in my app even if they are deleted from gallery. In that case, will saving URL be a good idea ?